# How to create a network diagram based on id and post?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm new to R and want to create a network diagram basically does this

| postid | userid |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| -------- | -------------- |

where user1 and user2 are connected to each other and user 2,4,5 is connected to each other too,amd there should be an edge between user 1 and user 4 since they both posted in post 2
basically all i want is to generate a network diagram to show users who talked in the same post.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(text="postid   userid
3   2
3   4
3   5
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   4", header = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
df %>%
  left_join( df, by = "postid" ) %>%
  select(-postid) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
  simplify( remove.multiple = TRUE, remove.loops = TRUE) %>%
  plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, is there a way not showing p1 and p2 and ps? basically just show connection of each users? since my data is quite large

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
glst <- lapply(
  with(df, split(as.character(userid), postid)),
  function(x) graph_from_data_frame(t(combn(x, 2)), directed = FALSE)
)
```

or

```
lapply(
  with(df, split(as.character(userid), postid)),
  function(x) simplify(graph_from_data_frame(expand.grid(x, x), directed = FALSE))
)
```

which produces a list of graph ojbects

```
$`1`
IGRAPH 125b424 UN-- 2 1 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edge from 125b424 (vertex names):
[1] 1--2

$`2`
IGRAPH 125bde9 UN-- 2 1 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edge from 125bde9 (vertex names):
[1] 1--4

$`3`
IGRAPH 125bde9 UN-- 3 3 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from 125bde9 (vertex names):
[1] 2--4 2--5 4--5
```

---

If you want to aggregate all sub-graphs, you can use `graph.union`

```
> (g <- do.call(graph.union, glst))
IGRAPH 7c8e074 UN-- 4 5 --
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from 7c8e074 (vertex names):
[1] 4--5 2--5 2--4 1--4 1--2
```

[image]

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(postid = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), userid = c(2L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-7L))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, but i do get this ncol value error where  Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : stating either its too big or contain NA. but my data frame does not contain na

Comment: @LUCAS99 Could you use `dput(head(df))` to share a piece of your data? I have no idea what happened with your read data.

Comment: @LUCAS99 You can try `split(as.character(AuthorID), ThreadID)`. You can see my updated answer with `expand.grid`.

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding then it gives me this Error in adjacent_vertices(x, i, mode = if (directed) "out" else "all") : 
  At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id

Comment: @LUCAS99 That's weird ... I can run it without any problem given the data from your comment.

Comment: Yea,idk why but i got this error from wimple's code Error in simplify(., remove.multiple = TRUE, remove.loops = TRUE) : 
  unused arguments (remove.multiple = TRUE, remove.loops = TRUE) which i dont know why its happening

Comment: @LUCAS99 If your dataset is not large, you can use `dput(df)` to share your compete data.